# Google Calendar API 403 error -- Android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-calendar-api, http-status-code-403

We are working on an Android App and getting this error:

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
"code": 403,
"errors": [
{
"domain": "usageLimits",
"message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.",
"reason": "accessNotConfigured"
} ...

I have tried:

1. Turning on the Calendar API in the console
2. Filling out the Google Console consent screen
3. Turning on the JSON API
4. Deleting the debug.keystore and re-generating the SHA1 key in eclipse and updating it in Google Console
5. Re-generating the API Key in Google Console and integrating it into the Android code in the Manifest
6. Doing a clean build of the Android code

What else an it be?

Comment: hi, i ran into this trouble too, do u mind sharing what u did to solve it ??

Comment: it wasn't me.  it was them.  it just resolved.  in our already uploaded android app.  without any changes on our part ...